# Passport.js Signin error

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Getting the below error when trying to signin using a valid account

```
    if(!user.authenticate(password)){
               ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/config/strategies/local.js:19:16)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at /home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1406:13
    at model.Document.init (/home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:254:11)
    at completeOne (/home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1404:10)
    at Immediate.cb (/home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1158:11)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/kj/Desktop/nodejs-exp/MEAN_BOOK/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:137:16)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
```

below is my locals.js which gets invoked during authentication

```
module.exports = function(){
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username,password,done){
    User.findOne({
      username:username
    },function(err,user){
      if(err){
        return done(err);
      }
      if(!user){
        return done(null,false,{
          message:'Unknown User'
        });
      }
      if(!user.authenticate(password)){
        return done(null,false,{
          message:'Invalid password'
        });
      }

      return done(null,user);
    });
  }));
};
```

And my routes.js file

```
module.exports = function(app){
  app.route('/signup')
    .get(users.renderSignup)
    .post(users.signup);

  app.route('/signin')
    .get(users.renderSignin)
    .post(passport.authenticate('local',{
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/signin',
      failureFlash : true
    }));

  app.get('/signout',users.signout);
};
```

My User Model:

```
  var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName : String,
    email: {
      type: String,
      match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, "Please fill a valid e-mail address"]
    },
    username : {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required:'Username is required',
      unique : true
    },
    password : {
      type:String,
      validate:[
        function(password){
          return password && password.length>6;
        },'Password should be longer'
      ]
    },
    sale:{
      type:String
    },
    provider:{
      type:String,
      required:'Provider is required'
    },
    providerId:String,
    providerDate:{},
    created : {
      type : Date,
      default : Date.now
    }
  });
```

I'm usure what the error means. please let me know if you require further info to debug the problem.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your `User` model?

Comment: @robertklep - added the schema

Comment: are you sure that User has an `authenticate` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your schema is missing an [instance method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) called `authenticate()`. This is something that isn't provided automatically, so you need to implement it yourself.

Judging by your code, it may be as simple as this:

```
UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {
  return this.password === password;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply:

```
 if(user.password !== password){
    return done(null,false,{
      message:'Invalid password'
    });
  }
```

The User model has no `authenticate` method.

Comment: I think that if user is not undefined then you could get his password that way, and then compare with the password given for authentication @robertklep

Comment: I think you mean `user.password !== password`